# new table and association has been added as icollection not ienuremable, how can i iterate through results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

ive added a new table to my entity and created an association. my new code is as below.

as you can see all previously added tables just go in with a get/set this table has got in as an icollection and in my razor view i cannot do the following anymore. how can i get the results into this view?

Thanks

Razor that no longer works
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NetInfo.Username)

Error

```
 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ITAPP.Models.tblNetworkInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Username' and no extension method 'Username' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ITAPP.Models.tblNetworkInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Class
    public partial class tblEquipment
    {
        public tblEquipment()
        {
            this.NetInfo = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PreviousUserID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ChangeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public bool Stock { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }


    public virtual tblUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual tblChangeLog ChangeLog { get; set; }
    public virtual tblAssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblNetworkInfo> NetInfo { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NetInfo is a collection you have to loop through it:

This is one option:

```
@foreach(var netInfo in Model.NetInfo)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => netInfo.Username)
}
```

Another option is:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NetInfo)
```

Then if you create a Display Template for the tblNetworkInfo model you can display whatever you need in it:

```
tblNetworkInfo.cshtml
----
@model tblNetworkInfo

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Username)
```

DisplayFor is smart enough to work on collections and output a display template for each item in the collection.

Comment: I think I have the relationship wrong then? there will only be 1 netinfo per equipment, but equipment may not have a netinfo at all, how should i set this relation up? Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a collection then don't use ICollection<T>. That implies a 1 to many scenario. If you have a 1 : 1 scenario then just do public virtual tblNetworkInfo NetInfo